# AngularJs: Form Post to a remote server gives error as Access to restricted URI denied

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and trying to learn it. So I was writing a demo application which tries to post the form data to site running on localhost. The code for the same is given below

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DemoApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <app-form></app-form>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app-form.html**

```
<h4>Form</h4>
<form ng-submit="appForm.submit();">
  <div ng-repeat="field in appForm.fields">
    <input type="{{field.type}" placeholder="{{field.placeholder}}" ng-model="appForm.data[field.name]">
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<h4>Form data - live - JSON</h4>
<pre>{{appForm.data | json}}</pre>

<h4>Form data - live - URL encoded</h4>
<pre>{{appForm.data | urlEncode}}</pre>

<div ng-if="appForm.dataSubmitted">
<h4>Form data - submitted - URL encoded</h4>
<pre>{{appForm.dataSubmitted}}</pre>
</div>

<div class="err" ng-repeat="error in errors"> {{error}}</div>
<div class="info" ng-repeat="msg in msgs">{{msg}}</div>
```

**js/script.js**

```
angular.module('DemoApp', [])

 // Form directive
.directive('appForm', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: 'AppFormCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'app-form.html'
  };
})

 // Form controller
.controller('AppFormCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$httpParamSerializer', function($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializer) {
  $scope.errors = [];
  $scope.msgs = [];
  $scope.appForm = {
    fields: [
      {name: 'name', type:'text', placeholder: 'Name (Bob York)'},
      {name: 'age', type:'text', placeholder: 'Age (21)'},
      {name: 'email', type:'email', placeholder: 'Email (example@example.com)'}
    ],

    data: {
      name: '',
      age: '',
      email: ''
    },

    dataSubmitted: '',

    submit: function() {
       // Here you would normally post the data to the server
       // Note how the data property is assigned explicitly a value url-encoded by the new service
       // Note the headers and the lack of transformRequest
       // $httpParamSerializerJQLike can also be used

      $http.post({
        url: 'http://localhost/<site>/api.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $httpParamSerializer($scope.appForm.data),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
            //TODO
            if(data.msg !='')
            {
                $scope.msg.push(data.msg);
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
            }

      }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
                        $scope.errors.push(status);
      });


       // Demo value to show url-encoding upon submission
      $scope.appForm.dataSubmitted = $httpParamSerializer($scope.appForm.data);
    }
  };
}])

 // Demo filter to show url-encoding live preview
.filter('urlEncode', ['$httpParamSerializer', function($httpParamSerializer) {
  var urlEncodeFilter = function(formData) {
    return $httpParamSerializer(formData);
  };

  urlEncodeFilter.$stateful = true;

  return urlEncodeFilter;
}]);
```

So when I tries to submit the data I get error as below

```
"Error: Access to restricted URI denied
createHttpBackend/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:10506:6
sendReq@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:10325:0
$http/serverRequest@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:10037:15
processQueue@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:14551:27
scheduleProcessQueue/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:14567:26
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:15830:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:15641:14
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:15935:12
ngEventHandler/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:23244:16
createEventHandler/eventHandler@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js:3264:8
"
```

The site to which this request is being made is running a PHP code and can understand url encoded data (for which I am doing serialization of the request data). But not able to get why this error is getting reported. Do I am missing something due to which this request is getting failed.

Comment: Are you running your angular js code on localhost as well or just open the files in the browser? If you are just opening it in your browser it looks like you might be getting a browser security error.

Comment: I was using a browser to open the file and then perform the test,. I will check with running the code on localhost and check again.

Comment: Move all the files to the httpd server html directory and then open it from the browser. Now I am getting 404 for an request URL `http://localhost/anj/[object Object]`. Now I m not getting how the requested url got changed as I made a POST request for `http://localhost/<site>/api.php` any thoughts to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the solution of this issue. As I was facing this issue due to CORS. So to solve it I have added below lines in httpd.conf file to make it accessible in the network

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>
```

Also please make sure that mod_headers module is enabled. For more information please take a look to [W3 Cors Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled)